# jQuery: menus appear/disappear on click

Tags: jquery, megamenu

I've been looking all over the web and I can't find a solution. I am very new to jQuery as well.

**My case:**

I have a nav bar, each link in it activates/triggers a megamenu (each link has its own megamenu).

**What I need:**

I need a way to have each link activate its own megamenu, the megamenu should close when:

1. The user clicks on another item in the nav bar.
2. The user clicks on the same item in the nav bar.
3. The user clicks on a 'close button' (X) graphic inside the megamenu (not shown in the HTML for simplicity sake).

**HTML:**

```
<div id="top-nav">
 <ul>
  <li><span>Products &amp; Services</span>
    <ul>
      <li><div class="megamenu">Content here...</div></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span>Support &amp; Training</span>
    <ul>
     <li> <div class="megamenu">Content here...</div></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span>Communities</span>
    <ul>
     <li> <div class="megamenu">Content here...</div></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span>Store</span>
    <ul>
      <li><div class="megamenu">Content here...</div></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I've seen the script of 'Sexy Drop Down Menu' but the problem is that it closes the menu triggered by the click on hover, and as I said, I'm new to jQuery and I can't figure out a way to adapt it to what I need.

http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/examples/drop-down-menu/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would attach a click handler to another item/same item/close button which would read something like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#top-nav span').click(function(){
        divTrigger = $('#top-nav span').index(this);
        thisMegaMenu = $('.megamenu:eq('+divTrigger+')');
        $('.megamenu').slideUp(200);
        if(thisMegaMenu.is(":not(':visible')")){
        thisMegaMenu.slideDown(200);
        }
});
    $('.megamenu').append("<a href=# id=closeButton>x</a>");
    $('#closeButton').live('click',function(){
        thisMegaMenu.slideUp(200);
    });
});
```

[Try it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/Wv4G2/1/)

Comment: bozdoz, your solution worked perfectly. I'm not all the way sure if I want to append the close button inside the script, but this is definitely the script that solves every single thing I needed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: And thank you Ricardo.  My first accepted answer.  I put the close button in just for fun. :)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this other solution which works like a charm as well:

```
$(function(){
//Megamenus
$('#top-nav li').click(function(){//set up a click event for the li
    $(this).siblings('.active').click();//click any other lis which are active to close their menus
    $(this).find('.megamenu').toggle();//toggle the child megamenu
    $(this).toggleClass('active');//toggle a class so we can identify any open megamenus
});

$('.megamenu').click(function(event){//hide the megamenu on load and set up a click event..
    $(this).parents('li').click();//..that just clicks the parent li
    event.stopPropagation();//stop the click bubbling up to the parent li
  });
});
```

My problem now is which of both solutions is better to use? This is a good problem now though :p

Solution provided at: http://codingforums.com/showpost.php?p=1016305&postcount=2

Answer (score 0):

For each of the higher level `<li>`s in the Navbar, give them a class like 'navbar'. Then your jQuery could look something like this:

```
$('li .navbar').click(function() {
  if($(this).find('.megamenu').is(':visible')) { // Already open
    $(this).find('.megamenu').hide();
  } else { // Close others first
    $('.megamenu').each(function() {
      $(this).hide();
    });
    $(this).find('.megamenu').show();
  }
});
```

You would just need to add the click handler for the Close button. Note, this is untested code so let me know if there's a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Aaron. However, my code inspector is telling me that there's a syntax error here: $(this).find('.megamenu').show(); - Although I'm not a jQuery/JS expert, I don't see anything wrong in that line... do you? I tried your code as is anyway, but no, it doesn't work. I did find a solution though, see my answer below. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh, my mistake, I forgot to close the .each function in the lines prior. See post for edits.

Comment: Code is fine now but still is not working, not sure why... Thanks a lot for your time and help.