# Onclick Display Block to None and None to Block

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have this code:
CSS:

```
 .hiddenlinks{display: none;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="expand">

<a href="javascript://" class="business" >123</a>
    <div class="hiddenlinks">
         <a href="/"target="_blank" class="business" style="color:#f36523">ABC</a><br />
         <a href="/"target="_blank" class="business" style="color:#f36523">DEF</a><br />
         <a href="/"target="_blank" class="business" style="color:#f36523">HIJ</a>
    </div>
 </div>
```

There is a list of similar div ids in a vertical order. What I am trying to do is once "123" is clicked, the divs id under #expand will shift down and the "ABC", "DEF", and "HIJ" will display:block.

So my question is a two parter:

1. How can i toggle display block and none on click with this html?
2. Is there a way to animate the separation of the div id's once .hiddenlinks goes from display:none to display:block. and also when .hiddenlinks goes back to display:none and the div ids close the gap.

Comment: sorry where is the #expand div?

Comment: you should view the topic and use toggle visibility (javascript function) to change display none settings: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15636682/2131877

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/F5NCt/1/

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"><<<< this goes in the header 
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".business").click(function(){
    $(".hiddenlinks").slideToggle();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="expand">

<a href="javascript://" class="business" >123</a>
    <div class="hiddenlinks">
         <a href="/"target="_blank" class="business" style="color:#f36523">ABC</a><br />
         <a href="/"target="_blank" class="business" style="color:#f36523">DEF</a><br />
         <a href="/"target="_blank" class="business" style="color:#f36523">HIJ</a>
    </div>
 </div>
</body>





    .hiddenlinks { 
display:none;
}
```

i have created a example for you i hope it helps once you click 123 the options drop down 
to your second question i m not sure but i think if you will have different id divs for each of your hidden link then in .slideToggle(//inside here you can customise how each div is shown\);

please see

www.jquery.com

also see the example above

hope it helps you